# call to Rollback transaction, was not expected, next expectation is: ExpectedQuery

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-sqlmock

I am trying to wrote this test bellow, other tests works fine, however I am having problems with the `UPDATE` query

```
func TestDeleteWorkspace(t *testing.T) {
    conn, mock, repository, err := setup()
    defer conn.Close()
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    uid := uuid.New()

    // mock.ExpectBegin()
    mock.ExpectQuery(regexp.QuoteMeta(`UPDATE "workspaces" SET`)).WithArgs(sqlmock.AnyArg(), uid)
    // mock.ExpectCommit()

    var e bool
    e, err = repository.Delete(uid)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    assert.True(t, e)

    err = mock.ExpectationsWereMet()
    assert.NoError(t, err)
}
```

`repository.Delete` does this query

```
func (r *WorkspaceRepository) Delete(id any) (bool, error) {
    if err := r.db.Delete(&model.Workspace{}, "id = ?", id).Error; err != nil {
        return false, nil
    }

    return true, nil
}
```

Which runs this query

```
UPDATE "workspaces" SET "deleted_at"='2022-07-04 09:09:20.778' WHERE id = 'c4610193-b43a-4ed7-9ed6-9d67b3f97502' AND "workspaces"."deleted_at" IS NULL
```

I am using **Soft-Delete**, that is why it is an UPDATE and not a DELETE query

However, I get the following error

```
    workspace_test.go:169: 
                Error Trace:    workspace_test.go:169
                Error:          Received unexpected error:
                                there is a remaining expectation which was not matched: ExpectedQuery => expecting Query, QueryContext or QueryRow which:
                                  - matches sql: 'UPDATE "workspaces" SET'
                                  - is with arguments:
                                    0 - 28e7aa46-7a22-4dc7-b3ce-6cf02af525ca
                                    1 - {}
```

What I am doing wrong?

EDIT: It is a soft-delete operation, that why is a UPDATE and not a DELETE

My model

```
type Workspace struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4()" json:"id"`
    Name      string         `gorm:"not null,type:text" json:"name"`
    CreatedAt time.Time      `gorm:"autoCreateTime" json:"create_time"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time      `gorm:"autoUpdateTime" json:"update_time"`
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index,->" json:"-"`
}
```

Comment: could you please post the entire code that would show how have you used transaction in the `Delete` call please

Comment: It just this line `db.Delete(&model.Workspace{}, "id = ?", id)`, however,  I am using software, that why is a UPDATE

Comment: I was asking about the function inside which you have written this line of `db.Delete`

Comment: and if this is a `DELETE` why are you expecting `UPDATE` query? shouldn't it be `DELETE * FROM workspaces`?

Comment: It is a SoftDelete. The query is `UPDATE "workspaces" SET "deleted_at"='2022-07-04 09:09:20.778' WHERE id = 'c4610193-b43a-4ed7-9ed6-9d67b3f97502' AND "workspaces"."deleted_at" IS NULL`

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: `return false, nil` should be `return false, err`. You will see real SQL parameters in that error. Something is wrong with it.

Comment: Added the model to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is quite self-explanatory.

This is your query:

```
'UPDATE "workspaces" SET "deleted_at"=$1 WHERE id = $2 AND "workspaces"."deleted_at" IS NULL'
```

it includes 2 arguments:

```
"deleted_at"=$1 WHERE id = $2
```

You set only 1 in your SQL mock:

```
.WithArgs(uid)
```

You need to send both arguments in mock.

It is not reliable to use `Time.Now()` in test because that value occasionally is going to be a few nanoseconds different from the value you set in code and test will fail.

The quick and dirty fix is to use `sqlmock.AnyArg()`:

```
.WithArgs(sqlmock.AnyArg(), uid)
```

A more sophisticated alternative is to write custom `Argument` that checks type and compares value with `time.Now()`. Difference should be less than a few seconds.

See an example: https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock#matching-arguments-like-timetime

Comment: Thank you. I did what you sugest and now I have another error. I have no idea how to fix, I updated my question, could you please see it again?

Comment: @Rodrigo can you please return an original question and post second one as an update? This resource is intended to be a public knowledge base, and it is hard to use it that way if questions are out of sync with answers. 

Regarding your new error, I guess that code does not trigger SQL update statement. Please post `repository.Delete` code if you need more help.

Comment: One issue from top of my head: `return false, nil` should be `return false, err`

Comment: Fixed this, added return false, err

Comment: Check that error. It should contain hint.

Comment: call to ExecQuery 'UPDATE "workspaces" SET "deleted_at"=$1 WHERE id = $2 AND "workspaces"."deleted_at" IS NULL' with args [{Name: Ordinal:1 Value:2022-07-04 10:49:53.9065059 -0300 -03} {Name: Ordinal:2 Value:72d7217f-b919-4b19-b401-13fef20cf47b}], was not expected, next expectation is: ExpectedQuery => expecting Query, QueryContext or QueryRow which:
                                  - matches sql: 'UPDATE "workspaces" SET'

Comment: I created another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72856621/there-is-a-remaining-expectation-which-was-not-matched-expectedquery-expecti