# there is a remaining expectation which was not matched: ExpectedQuery => expecting Query, QueryContext or QueryRow which

Tags: go-gorm, go-sqlmock

I have this repository

```
func (r *WorkspaceRepository) Delete(id any) (bool, error) {
    if err := r.db.Delete(&model.Workspace{}, "id = ?", id).Error; err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    return true, nil
}
```

Which does a **Soft-Delete**, the query which this Delete operation runs is this one

> UPDATE "workspaces" SET "deleted_at"='2022-07-04 09:09:20.778' WHERE id = 'c4610193-b43a-4ed7-9ed6-9d67b3f97502' AND "workspaces"."deleted_at" IS NULL

My test

```
uid := uuid.New()

mock.ExpectBegin()
mock.ExpectQuery(regexp.QuoteMeta(`UPDATE "workspaces" SET`)).WithArgs(sqlmock.AnyArg(), uid)
mock.ExpectCommit()

_, err = repository.Delete(uid)
assert.NoError(t, err)
```

I got the error

```
    workspace_test.go:165: 
                Error Trace:    workspace_test.go:165
                Error:          Received unexpected error:
                                call to ExecQuery 'UPDATE "workspaces" SET "deleted_at"=$1 WHERE id = $2 AND "workspaces"."deleted_at" IS NULL' with args [{Name: Ordinal:1 Value:2022-07-04 10:54:16.4863731 -0300 -03} {Name: Ordinal:2 Value:ae4124d9-ed16-4dcf-beb9-fcdcf27ca7da}], was not expected, next expectation is: ExpectedQuery => expecting Query, QueryContext or QueryRow which:
                                  - matches sql: 'UPDATE "workspaces" SET'
                                  - is with arguments:
                                    0 - {}
                                    1 - ae4124d9-ed16-4dcf-beb9-fcdcf27ca7da; call to Rollback transaction, was not expected, next expectation is: ExpectedQuery => expecting Query, QueryContext or QueryRow which:
                                  - matches sql: 'UPDATE "workspaces" SET'
                                  - is with arguments:
                                    0 - {}
                                    1 - ae4124d9-ed16-4dcf-beb9-fcdcf27ca7da
                Test:           TestDeleteWorkspace
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me some time to figure out, but again, `sqlmock` error explains the problem if you know how to read the error message.

In our code, we execute `UPDATE` statement that triggers `Exec` db driver command instead of `Query` that is used for selects.

The error message explains that `sqlmock` expects code to perform one of these operations:

> next expectation is: ExpectedQuery => expecting Query, QueryContext or
> QueryRow

We need to use `ExpectExec()` instead of `ExpectQuery()` in test to match our code. We also need to define how many records are `updated` in our mocked DB by adding `WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))`.

Fix one line and test should pass:

```
mock.ExpectExec(regexp.QuoteMeta(`UPDATE "workspaces" SET`)).WithArgs(sqlmock.AnyArg(), uid).WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))
```